# Find, remove and wrap part of url using RegEx

Tags: regex

I need help writing a regex that allows me to find and replace parts of urls. I need to find strings inbetween `:` and `/` or nothing (since it might be the end of the string), remove the character `:`, and then wrap it in `{}`.

This is what the strings can look like

```
/submissions/search
/submissions/:_id
/points/:serial
/deals/:_id/search
```

This is what I want them to look like after running `String.replace()`:

```
/submissions/search
/submissions/{_id}
/points/{serial}
/deals/{_id}/search
```

Ps. Background for this is that I need to generate [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/) specifications from [Express](https://expressjs.com/). Express uses ":" for dynamic parameters while OpenAPI uses {}. The regex would be the same no matter the use case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex**: [`:([^\/\n]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/09wVGQ/1)

Details:

- `()` Group
- `[^]` Match a single character not present in the list
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `\1` Group 1.

**Substitution**: `{\1}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: `:([^/]+)(\/|$)`

- `:` -> detects the `:`
- `([^/]+)` -> captures one or more that's not a `/`
- `(\/|$)` -> detects `/` or end of string
- g -> replaces multiple occurences in string

```js
var urls = [
  '/submissions/search',
  '/submissions/:_id',
  '/points/:serial',
  '/deals/:_id/search',
  '/deals/:_id/:serial/search', //will detect more than one
];

for(var i = 0, l = urls.length; i < l; i++){
  console.log(urls[i].replace(/:([^/]+)(\/|$)/g, '{$1}$2'));
}
```